# C#: Get name of Static Members

Tags: c#

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass A = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass B = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass C = new MyClass();

    public static IEnumerable<MyClass> List() => new[] {A,B,C };
}
```

Calling this code:

```
foreach (var item in MyClass.List())
{
    Debug.Print(nameof(item));
}
```

..will return:

```
item
item
item
```

But I want it to show this instead:

```
A
B
C
```

How can I make that happen?

--Edit--
#Sinatr in the comment give a good fairly simple suggestion using a Dictionary instead

```
public static Dictionary<MyClass, string> List()
{
    return new Dictionary<MyClass, string>()
    {
            { A, nameof(A) },
            { B, nameof(B) },
            { C, nameof(C) },
    };
}
```

Comment: You will have to create a list of strings or MemberInfo/FieldInfo objects. the objects in your List does not have names, nor do they know "their names", nor do they retain the information from which field they came from.

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem

Comment: Create a companion method for `MyClass.List()`: `public static IEnumerable<MyClass> ListNames() => new[] {nameof(A), nameof(B), nameof(C) };`

Comment: For enum-like class you will need to pass names inside. Add `Name` property to a class and set it for all constants. Otherwise having only instance (from e.g. `A` field) will not tell you anything. Another solution is to use dictionary as result of method returning all constants: key is the name, value is the instance.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options I can think of at the moment:

##### 1. Use `System.Reflection`

```
typeof(MyClass)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(field => field.Name)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

##### 2. Add a companion method

As hinted in the comments, add a companion method to `List()` like `ListNames()` that returns an `IEnumerable`  of names:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass A = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass B = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass C = new MyClass();

    public static IEnumerable<MyClass> List() => new[] {A, B, C };
    public static IEnumerable<MyClass> ListNames() => new[] 
    {
        nameof(A), 
        nameof(B), 
        nameof(C) 
    };

}
```